# Getting 2 Assemblies as same Path while using Assembly.LoadFrom method.Why?

Tags: c#-4.0

```
 string Version1_dll = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Version1_dll"];//New_Dll

 string Version2_dll = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Version2_dll"];//Old Dll

 Assembly assembly1 = Assembly.LoadFrom(Version1_dll);
 Assembly assembly2 = Assembly.LoadFrom(Version2_dll);
```

In the above code,reading the `2` dll files and fetching the data like Controllers, methods and its Parameters.

But,Here the Problem is `Assembly.LoadFrom(Version2_dll)` overrides and showing same (Version1_dll) dll path  in 2 objects.

Answer (score 0):

- For this particular issue there is only copy of DLL possible in Application Domain.
- This is why when you load newer version It will not load already present in Application Domain.
- Here Like When you add such assembly ( Both are same) then it is possible then both have same namespace so it get confused so it will not allow to load.

**Note :  For more detail you have to dig how assembly load works.**

Solution 1:

To solve this you have to give DLL version number in AssemblyInfo.cs. If you specify different version then it will allow to load both. ( Also don't forget to provide strongname in signing section of project.).